# Need advice on rotating gripper to avoid collisions during palletizing

Tags: ros2

I'm currently working on a project involving palletizing boxes using a Universal Robot controlled by a ROS system. The palletizing process involves picking up boxes from a conveyor belt and placing them onto a pallet. However, I've encountered an issue with potential collisions between the gripper, robot arm, and existing boxes on the pallet.

To mitigate these collisions, I'm looking to rotate the gripper before placing certain boxes onto the pallet. My system communicates with an Allen Bradley CompactLogix PLC for which i used pylogix, which then sends commands to the Universal Robot.

Could you please provide guidance on how to implement this rotation logic within my ROS system? I'm particularly interested in understanding how to coordinate the rotation command with the palletizing sequence and how to ensure that the gripper rotates only when necessary.

Any advice, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

ROS version: Humble
PLC: Compactlogix

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a way point before you reach the goal where you would orient the gripper to avoid hitting the other boxes.